# packages from router dont match iptables dnat rule

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, nat

I have the follow rules to forward port 443 from external to a internal host:

```
IF_INET=ppp0
IF_INET_IP=1.2.3.4    # Router External IP
IF_LAN_IP=192.168.0.1 # Router Internal IP
IF_LAN_NET=192.168.0.0/24
VPN_HOST=192.168.0.2  # Internet Host with a HTTPS Webserver

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d $IF_INET_IP -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to $VPN_HOST
iptables -A FORWARD -i $IF_INET -o $IF_LAN -p tcp -d $VPN_HOST --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

That the service is also reachable from internal I also have a snat rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d $VPN_HOST -p tcp --dport 443 -s $IF_LAN_NET -j SNAT --to $IF_LAN_IP
```

Problem is now, when I wanna open the dns-address (which points to $IF_INET_IP) from the router itself where iptables in doing the nat, that packages get not forwarded to the internal host.

I definied the follow rules to trace the problem:

```
iptables -t raw -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d $IF_INET_IP --dport 443 -j TRACE
```

and got this:

```
TRACE: raw:OUTPUT:rule:6 IN= OUT=lo SRC=1.2.3.4 DST=1.2.3.4 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35855 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=35594 DPT=443 SEQ=89529104 ACK=0 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (0204FFD70402080A02C9971F0000000001030307) UID=0 GID=0
TRACE: raw:OUTPUT:policy:7 IN= OUT=lo SRC=1.2.3.4 DST=1.2.3.4 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35855 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=35594 DPT=443 SEQ=89529104 ACK=0 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (0204FFD70402080A02C9971F0000000001030307) UID=0 GID=0
TRACE: mangle:OUTPUT:policy:1 IN= OUT=lo SRC=1.2.3.4 DST=1.2.3.4 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35855 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=35594 DPT=443 SEQ=89529104 ACK=0 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (0204FFD70402080A02C9971F0000000001030307) UID=0 GID=0
TRACE: nat:OUTPUT:policy:1 IN= OUT=lo SRC=1.2.3.4 DST=1.2.3.4 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35855 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=35594 DPT=443 SEQ=89529104 ACK=0 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (0204FFD70402080A02C9971F0000000001030307) UID=0 GID=0
TRACE: filter:OUTPUT:rule:1 IN= OUT=lo SRC=1.2.3.4 DST=1.2.3.4 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35855 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=35594 DPT=443 SEQ=89529104 ACK=0 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (0204FFD70402080A02C9971F0000000001030307) UID=0 GID=0
TRACE: mangle:POSTROUTING:policy:1 IN= OUT=lo SRC=1.2.3.4 DST=1.2.3.4 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35855 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=35594 DPT=443 SEQ=89529104 ACK=0 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (0204FFD70402080A02C9971F0000000001030307) UID=0 GID=0
TRACE: nat:POSTROUTING:policy:4 IN= OUT=lo SRC=1.2.3.4 DST=1.2.3.4 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35855 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=35594 DPT=443 SEQ=89529104 ACK=0 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (0204FFD70402080A02C9971F0000000001030307) UID=0 GID=0
TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:rule:4 IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=1.2.3.4 DST=1.2.3.4 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35855 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=35594 DPT=443 SEQ=89529104 ACK=0 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (0204FFD70402080A02C9971F0000000001030307)
TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:rule:6 IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=1.2.3.4 DST=1.2.3.4 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35855 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=35594 DPT=443 SEQ=89529104 ACK=0 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (0204FFD70402080A02C9971F0000000001030307)
TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:7 IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=1.2.3.4 DST=1.2.3.4 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35855 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=35594 DPT=443 SEQ=89529104 ACK=0 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (0204FFD70402080A02C9971F0000000001030307)
TRACE: mangle:PREROUTING:policy:1 IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=1.2.3.4 DST=1.2.3.4 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35855 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=35594 DPT=443 SEQ=89529104 ACK=0 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (0204FFD70402080A02C9971F0000000001030307)
TRACE: mangle:INPUT:policy:1 IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=1.2.3.4 DST=1.2.3.4 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35855 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=35594 DPT=443 SEQ=89529104 ACK=0 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (0204FFD70402080A02C9971F0000000001030307)
TRACE: filter:INPUT:rule:2 IN=lo OUT= MAC=00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:08:00 SRC=1.2.3.4 DST=1.2.3.4 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=35855 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=35594 DPT=443 SEQ=89529104 ACK=0 WINDOW=43690 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0 OPT (0204FFD70402080A02C9971F0000000001030307)
```

Andy Idea how I can do it?

Comment: Not sure what your problem is, but you might want to setup a [TRACE rule](http://serverfault.com/questions/122157/debugger-for-iptables/126079#126079) to debug your problem.

Comment: I updated my question with the trace.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found the solution to my problem:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d $IF_INET_IP -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to $VPN_HOST
```

It redirect the package direct on the output to the right direction.